# Why does PowerShell split arguments containing hyphens and periods?

Tags: powershell, syntax

In a PowerShell window:

```
PS C:\> echo -abc.def.ghi
-abc
.def.ghi
```

For some reason, the combination of a hyphen and period cause Powershell to split the argument into two lines.

It does not occur with without the hyphen:

```
PS C:\> echo abc.def.ghi
abc.def.ghi
```

Nor does it occur when there are no periods:

```
PS C:\> echo -abcdefghi
-abcdefghi
```

Through experimentation, I've found I can escape the behavior with a backtick:

```
PS C:\> echo `-abc.def.ghi
-abc.def.ghi
```

But *why* does this occur?  What fundamental part of PowerShell syntax am I not understanding?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I note `echo "-abc.def"` works as expected so that might be a hint

Comment: Assuming you are using PowerShell V3+, you can use this `{echo -abc.def.ghi}.Ast.EndBlock.Statements[0].PipelineElements[0].CommandElements` to see, how this is interpreted by parser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've disassembled Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility to look at the code of `Write-Output` nothing special there, it just iterates through InputObject and passes each to a `WriteObject` method implemented by the current `ICommandRuntime`.

[image: Disassembled <code>Write-Output</code>]

My guess is that the tokenizer that process the text tries to match anything starting with a `-` to a declared parameter. Failing that, it passes it through the pipeline as an item in `-InputObject`. Since a `.` cannot be a part of a variable name and therefore can't be part of a switch name it might separate it before doing the if check and when it turns out to be a parameter it doesn't join it back up with the rest of the token. You might therefore have found a minor bug.

When using the back tick or quotation marks it doesn't make this mistake however since it can tokenize the entire thing.

This is all conjecture though, I'd love to see a authoritative answer as much as you.

**Edit**

Evidence of what I'm saying:

```
PS> echo -NoEnumerate.foo
.foo
```

Comment: `.` can be part of variable name: `${Almost any character can be part of variable name.}`.

Comment: @PetSerAl well yeah, but not without braces so my argument still applies. But good point,

Comment: That's not a bug, that's a feature. `command -s.\localfile` then does what you want. The same behavior occurs for `command -s:localfile`, but not for `command -s#localfile`.

Comment: Just for clarification - it seems to occur on *any* command, not just `Write-Output` or `echo`.  It doesn't seem to matter if it's a Powershell cmdlet or just an exe or batch file, etc.

Comment: @JeroenMostert that's sine `#` is a comment delimiter isn't it?

Comment: @JeroenMostert `-s:localfile` not same at all. `:` means explicit value: `-Confirm:$false`.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: no, since it's not interpreted as a comment. You can pick another character if you like, say `-s!localfile`. The whole thing will be treated as a switch name (or, at least, a single token).

Comment: @PetSerAl: I was making no statement about the *meaning*. Just that the theory "this is a bug and it has something to do with variable names" is at best questionable. The parser splits `-s:localfile` and `-s.\localfile` because that's useful. Of course, using `localfile` in the case of `:` is confusing -- sorry about that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert see my edit, what about that? You notice that `echo -NoEnumerate.foo` will print *only* `.foo` since `-NoEnumerate` can be matched as a parameter

Comment: I'm running Powershell v3, and `echo -Confirm.foo` prints `-Confirm` and `.foo`. Same with `-NoEnumerate`.

Comment: Ah. For v3, use `echo -InputObject.foo` then, that just prints `.foo`. Since those parameters were only added in v4.

Comment: And not for `NoEnumerate`? That's so strange my eye just started twitching

Comment: This makes a lot of sense.  Thanks for the `-NoEnumerate.foo` example.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer [This](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849921(v=wps.620).aspx) says that there is no `-NoEnumerate` parameter in PowerShell V3.

Comment: With regard to this particular quirk - I don't think it matters which parameter we are talking about. The point is that if a command has a parameter that it can match on, then it will read the first part of the argument as that parameter name.

Answer (score 1):

FYI not sure if George was trying to mention this or not but `echo` is an alias for `Write-Output` in PowerShell.

```
PS C:\temp> Get-Alias echo

CommandType     Name                                               ModuleName                                                                                
-----------     ----                                               ----------                                                                                
Alias           echo -> Write-Output
```

In the example `echo -abc.def.ghi` the parser sees the unquoted hyphen as the prefix for a parameter/switch name. Period also has special meaning. Parameters cannot contain periods so the parser is treating that like the string terminator.

As a whole `write-output` sees it as an array so it is matched positionally to -InputObject

(I hope i'm not totally wrong with my assertions.)

Comment: So then, without the hyphen it's *not* considered a parameter?

Comment: It wont attempt to match it. It would just trying to assign it positionally at that point. I wouldnt try to parse the periods either. This is why quoting is a good practice