# Launching Java With Java_OPTS

Tags: java, windows, powershell, environment-variables

This should be a pretty simple question, I can't believe I wasn't able to find anything from googling.

I'm using powershell and I'm trying to run a java app from command line:

```
$memory = "-Xms128m -Xmx1028m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
$ssl = "-Djavax.rmi.ssl.client.enabledProtocols=`"TLSv1`" -Djavax.rmi.ssl.client.enabledCipherSuites=`"_removed_`" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=`"_removed_`" -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=`"_removed_`" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=`"_removed_`" -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=`"_removed_`" -Djava.endorsed.dirs=`"$($ddmsLoc)tomcat6\endorsed`""

$classpath = getClasspath "manager" $null
$java_opts = "$($memory) $($ssl) -Djavax.net.debug=all"
$cmd = "$($java) $($java_opts) -cp `"$($classpath)`" dss.vector.solutions.manager.server.ServerStatus -g"

Invoke-Expression $cmd
```

But for some reason it thinks my JAVA_OPTS parameters are the name of the java class I'm running:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: .rmi.ssl.client.enabledProtocols=TLSv1
```

I have tried:

1. The ssl options with/without quotes around the value
2. Actually setting the JAVA_OPTS environment variable, until I read somewhere else that the JVM doesn't ever read that variable.
3. wrapping them in more quotes

I'm kind of at a loss here.

Comment: Try with a straightforward java opt and assign it to $ssl and see if it works. The problem could be with other parts of your script as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614969/how-can-i-pass-batch-arguments-with-dots-into-a-powershell-script

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704867/why-does-powershell-split-arguments-containing-hyphens-and-periods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Etan Reisner posted a comment that helped me to solve it:

[Why does PowerShell split arguments containing hyphens and periods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28704867/why-does-powershell-split-arguments-containing-hyphens-and-periods)

Windows is (for some reason) splitting the parameters in half.

```
echo -Dmy.param=value
```

returns:

```
-Dmy
.param=value
```

If the parameter is wrapped in quotes, like:

```
echo "-Dmy.param=value"
```

Then it works just fine.